# Should I rebase master onto a branch that's been pushed?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

We use the [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) in our small team of developers. We're currently working on a large project, so one of the developers has pushed their feature branch to origin, where everyone else can checkout their own local copy.

```
[leonard@dev public]$ git branch -avv
  master                        9d53b40 [origin/master] Fix reviews
* responsive                    0c04643 [origin/responsive] Add media queries
  remotes/origin/HEAD           -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master         9d53b40 Fix reviews
  remotes/origin/responsive     0c04643 Add media queries
```

When developing on master, we create feature branches (i.e. master_hotfix), then when we're ready to merge it in we first rebase `master` on to it before doing so. This gives us a nice linear history that we prefer. We thought this would be the best way to do this with our responsive project too, so we would create a new branch (i.e. responsive_some-feature) based on the responsive branch. The same `git pull`, `git rebase responsive responsive_some-feature` can then be used here, too.

But we're a bit confused as to whether we should (and if so, at what point) rebase `master` on to `responsive`? Before the `responsive` branch was pushed to `origin`, rebasing `master` on to it was simple, but is rebasing `master` to `responsive` then `responsive` to `responsive_some-feature` correct? When I *do*, I see (along with a few conflicts) this:

```
# On branch responsive
# Your branch and 'origin/responsive' have diverged,
# and have 112 and 109 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Usually at this point I see a clean working directory, where I can then checkout `master` and merge my feature branch in. Alas, after this rebase the commits from `master` are in there, with the new commits in `responsive` coming after them, correctly, but is this the right method? How should I proceed, or should I use a different method to keep `responsive` up to date with `master`?

**Edit: I've made a graphic to illustrate my workflow better:**

[image]

Comment: If `responsive` branched off `master`, then why would you think of rebasing `master` on `responsive`?  Also, if you show diagrams instead of words, your question will be more clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying to match the Feature Branch Workflow - creating branches off master and then rebasing other peoples changes in to my branch before merging back in to master. The difference here being that branches are being made off of this feature branch too, if that makes sense.

Comment: I feel that your question isn't so much about rebasing, but rather sorting out the possibility that the feature might be ahead of the feature-feature, or vice-versa.  Also, to correct your terminology a bit: `merge my feature branch in.`  If a feature from `master` is ahead, you would really be fast-forwarding `master` (technically this is a fast-forward merge, but I don't like to use the word "merge" in the context of a rebase).

Comment: It's nice to have a linear history, but as soon as you have multiple developers working on feature branches and rebasing them, you've entered the "major surgery" realm of working with Git.  You may want to ask yourself whether you might be better served by keeping an accurate history (instead of a linear history) for major branches, and only use rebasing to keep these main branches linear.  Git can be a lot easier to use when you use an accurate history instead of a fictitious linear history.  Again, rebase is great for small changes but for big changes stick to merge, it's safer and easier.

Comment: I'm also concerned that you say you are rebasing master onto your feature branch... normally you do the opposite, you rebase your feature branch onto master.  I am confused as to why you are rebasing master at all.

Comment: If you can show us a sample diagram of `master` `feature` `feature-feature` maybe we can give some focused guidance.  As @DietrichEpp mentioned, there seems to be a bit of confusion about how to rebase, and this itself may be the actual source of your question.

Comment: Tthanks guys, I'll get a diagram sorted

Comment: I've added the graphic - I hope that clears things up. Essentially, like I said, I'm using the Feature Branch Workflow, but then pushing the brand and making a new feature from that too. I'm open for suggestions in terms of merging instead of rebasing for bigger features like this, thanks for the suggestion, though it *would* be nice to know where/what I'm doing wrong here so I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TLDR

> Should I rebase master onto a branch that's been pushed?

No, you should follow the general rule - `never rewrite the public history` (= never rebase branch that's been pushed).

In the case of simple feature branches, you are able to rebase them (rewrite history) before the push. Or, at least, you can be sure that only one developer works with the feature branch and do forced push if you have `branches have diverged` situation.

In the case of the `responsive` branch, it is public and used by many developers.
So you can not rebase it on top of master, do the regular merge for this branch.

Note: as mentioned in the comments, you have a bit confusing terminology in your post. So I assume that `...we first rebase master on to it [feature branch]...` actually means the opposite and you rebase feature branches on top of master.

### Explanation

The "normal" (no history rewrite) flow with feature branches look like this:

```
1) we have a feature branch 

... O ---- O ---- A ---- B  master
                   \
                    C       feature-branch

2) we do the merge, usually with merge commit (D)
   sometimes it can be fast-forward without the merge commit

... O ---- O ---- A -- B -- D -  master
                   \       /
                    -- C --      feature-branch
```

The flow with re-base:

```
1) we have a feature branch 

... O ---- O ---- A ---- B  master
                   \
                    C       feature-branch

2) we rebase feature branch on top of master
   note, that we changed the history and have new C' commit on 
   the feature branch

... O ---- O ---- A ---- B  master
                          \
                           C'  branch_xxx (feature branch)

3) we do the merge, master is fast-forwarded since there is nothing new
   on master

... O ---- O ---- A -- B -- C' -  master (fast forwarded)
                        \  /
                         C'      feature-branch
```

It works good if there is only one developer who works on the feature branch.
So the history rewrite is safe.

But when you add your `responsive` branch in, the flow, as I understand, is this:

```
1) we have a feature branch 

... O ---- O ---- A ---- B       master
                   \
                    R1 -- R2     responsive
                           \
                            F1   responsive-feature-branch

2) now see what happens if `responsive-feature-branch` is still active (someone works on it) and we rebase the `responsive` on top of `master`:

... O ---- O ---- A ---- B                master
                  \       \
                   \       R1' -- R2'     responsive'
                    \
                     R1 -- R2             responsive
                            \
                             F1           responsive-feature-branch
```

Do you see the problem? Now you have two `responsive` branches which are diverged (see also explanation in my [post](http://serebrov.github.io/html/2012-02-13-git-branches-have-diverged.html)).

You can push the rebased `responsive'` using '-f' (force) flag, but what will the developer who works on the `responsive-feature-branch` do? He'll just have the new upstream history and will have to rewrite his-own local history accordingly.

You can do this forced update if you are sure that nobody have active branches derived from `responsive` and everyone will need then update their local repos.

But I don't recommend this, because you can't guarantee that there are no active sub-branches and someday you'll definitely find that your repository has messed up.
I think that pretty linear history not worth the time you'll need to spend on resolving these issues.

Comment: This seems to make sense. In essence, I wouldn't rebase master, so why would I rebase responsive (as it's sort of acting a bit like "a master" now that it's pushed to origin). So, in this case, would you suggest just doing a `git merge` when all developers are finished on the responsive branch (and responsive feature branches)? What if a feature from master needed to be integrated in to responsive, for instance, before it was ready to go live? Or is that just one of the pitfalls here?

Comment: @LeonardChallis you can merge `responsive` to `master` and `master` to back to `responsive`. If you do the regular merge it should not be a problem. Once you updated the `responsive`, developers can update their local copies and merge to their responsive sub-branches (or rebase their responsive sub-branches on top of new version of the responsive branch).

Comment: @BorisSerebrov On the flow with re-base since it fast forwards I think it doesn't create a `D` commit, it just forwards the HEAD of master to `C`.

Comment: @giannischristofakis right, thank you, I updated the answer and changed D to C'.